# How to get the ScenarioContext when the same method executed multiple times?

Tags: c#, specflow

**Sample Feature 1:**

```
Scenario: Record Creation for different Users
   Given "User 1" is created a record
    And "User 2" is created a record
    And "User 3" is created a record
    Then admin is able to check all the record IDs
```

**Sample Feature 2:**

```
Scenario: Record Creation for guest User
   Given "guest User 1" is created a record
    Then admin is able to check all the record IDs
```

Here ,I am having one Common Specflow Steps for Step 2, 3 and 5 and  will get some unique ID from step 2,3 and 4. In Step 5, I need validate all the unique ID which is generated from step 2, 3 and 3.

**Sample Step definition:**

```
    [Given(@"""(.*)"" is created a record")]
    public void GivenIsCreatedARecord(string username)
    {
        var recordRef=<<some Logic >>;
        ScenarioContext.Current["Record Ref"] = recordRef;
    }
```

I have analyzed and used ScenarioContext to share the info between all the step. Here, I am  setting the Record Ref value in Scenario Context and accessing it in the Last Step for the verification (`var expectedID=ScenarioContext.Current["Record Ref"]`). But, implemented logic is working fine for the Feature 2 and User 3 id is getting updated for the feature 1 (since, the same method is executed 3 times).

Is there a way to hold User1 ID,User2 ID and Uuser 3 ID in some list and same thing can be accessed in verification step (all the ID info needs to be accessed within the scenario only)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scenario Outline

```
Scenario Outline: Record Creation for different Users
 Given '<user>' is created a record
 Then admin is able to check all the record IDs
 Examples:
 |user  |
 |User 1|
 |User 2|
 |User 3|
```

The test code

```
private Dictionary<string,SomeType> usersResult= new Dictionary<string,SomeType>();
[Given(@"""(.*)"" is created a record")]
public void GivenIsCreatedARecord(string username)
{
    var recordRef=<<some Logic >>;
    usersResult.add(username,recordRef);
    //other stuff
}
```